# Screen reader capturing hidden content on carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I have a carousel as follows. It scrolls horizontally on click.

I intent to only show 3 items at a time. Rest will be hidden via overflow hidden.

Clicking right or left will hide/reveal more tiles.

But the `screen reader` is currently reading out the hidden items too since it can capture the overflow hidden content.

This is wrong. It should have read out only the 3 visible items.

Imagine I have scrolled left once so item 1 is now hidden. Yet it still reads out:

> 1 long text ..

I could overcome this by adding `aria-hidden: true` for the hidden items.

Based on `currentPos`, update the `aria-hidden=true or false` values dynamically for each item. This works.

But this introduces a new problem.

There are 6 items. So previously the screen reader at start will read out.

> List 6 items. You are currently in a list.

But since now I am hiding items, it ends up reading only 3 items existing:

> List 3 items. You are currently in a list.

Not sure if this is acceptable by accessibility standards.

Is there a way around this.

The question is: How can I stop screen reader from reading hidden content.

But at the same time the screen should still know there are 6 items so that it can call that out as usual.

Is this even possible. Or the reducing in list size in the read out is acceptable. Not found any references on it.

P.S: Using mac's inbuilt screen reader for testing.

The component. Stylings not added here to keep it simple.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Carousel = () => {
  const [currentPos, setCurrentPos] = useState(0);

  const handleLeftClick = () => {
    if (currentPos === 0) return;
    setCurrentPos(currentPos - 1);
  };

  const handleRightClick = () => {
    setCurrentPos(currentPos + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="carousel">
      <ul className="carousel-inner" style={{ transform: `translateX(${-currentPos * 350}px)` }}>
        {/* is dynamic can have more or less than 6 items*/}
        <li className="carousel-item">1 long text ..</li>
        <li className="carousel-item">2 long text ..</li>
        <li className="carousel-item">3 long text ..</li>
        <li className="carousel-item">4 long text ..</li>
        <li className="carousel-item">5 long text ..</li>
        <li className="carousel-item">6 long text ..</li>
      </ul>
      <div className="carousel-arrow left" onClick={handleLeftClick}>&lt;</div>
      <div className="carousel-arrow right" onClick={handleRightClick}>&gt;</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Suggested solution for reference.

Using mac's default screen reader.

Won't work cos the screen reader reads out:

> List My Custom List 4 items

Was expecting just:

> My Custom List

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div>
        <button>Click me!</button>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <ul aria-label="My Custom List">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could populate an array with your `li` elements and set the `aria-label` for your ul to a dynamically computed value based on the number of list items (`aria-label={“List ${items.length} items”}`). Then you could go ahead and set the elements to hidden and still get an account count for the screen reader

Comment: You're trying to fix a problem that isn't a problem. You have 6 items in your list. A screen reader user may not care how many are visible if they can't see them so it's important to know there are 6 items. In fact, sighted users find it very helpful to know how many items are in a carousel even if they can't see them all. That's often possible if there's a "dot" menu under the carousel, with each dot representing a carousel item. A screen reader user has an advantage in this respect since they're told how many items there are.

Comment: @ionosphere Believe this would be a double read out. Once for the standard read saying there are 3 items on list. And a second time from this new aria label saying there are 6 items on list.

Comment: @slugolicious get your point but its an organisational requirement.

Comment: Can you expand on that? It’s an organizational requirement to *create* an accessibility issue? I don’t follow why there’s a requirement to try to change the metadata that the screen reader knows about and announces to the user.

Comment: @Kar Are you sure it would be a double readout?  It looks like it would override rather than double as long as you define it on the same element that produced the original readout. The official W3C spec for `aria-label` notes that `Authors should be aware that use of aria-label will override any native naming`: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA6.html

Comment: @slugolicious Not sure if I am explaining the issue properly. Have a look at this site for example. https://www.americanexpress.com/uk/credit-cards/gold-credit-card/ See that "How You Earn" side scroller. Imagine you clicked the right button once. So the first item is now hidden to the left. Try using a screen reader on it. The screen reader will still read out the first item incorrectly.. Imagine a person with partial visual impairment who still can see the page but using a screen reader. This is incorrect I believe. Don't think it is an exact 100% right or 100% wrong situation.

Comment: @ionosphere It produces mixed read out. Posted a simple reproducible example above. See under 'Suggested solution'.

Comment: @kar. Thanks. It should work without reading out ‘x items’ if you add `role=“none presentation”` to each individual list item and then the aria label to the ul as a whole. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929366/how-do-i-make-the-screen-reader-not-say-the-list-contains-certain-number-of-item

Comment: @ionosphere Thanks. That would work in hiding the default read out or if I use role="generic". But unfortunately we still want to maintain that this is a list. Using these loses that semantics. Starting to feel what I am looking for may not be possible.

Comment: @kar Wouldn’t you still be maintaining that it is a list with the custom aria-label of ‘list of x items’? It doesn’t seem like those semantics would be lost since you’d effectively be providing them  in place of the default ones.

Comment: @ionosphere, no, it wouldn't be a list any more just because you have a label saying it's a list. A screen reader user would not be able to navigate to it using the `L` shortcut key or navigate to individual listitems using the `I` shortcut key.  Also note that `role="none presentation"` is redundant. The stackoverflow response you pointed to said `none` wasn't fully supported yet but didn't give any proof of such. Both of those roles mean the same thing but `presentation` has been around longer and is fine to use by itself (when appropriate, which is not in this case).

Comment: @kar, thanks for the amex example. Hearing it say "list with 4 items" is absolutely correct. It doesn't matter that you can only visually see 3 of them. There are still 4 items in the list. If you had a really long vertical table, say with 1000 rows, but the browser could only show you 50 rows and to see more you have to scroll the browser down, a screen reader should not say there's a table with 50 rows just because you can't see them all.

Comment: Thanks for the details, @slugolicious! That makes good sense re: the difference.

Comment: @slugolicious Yes you are right. And that is what I am trying to achieve. If there is 4 items and only showing 3 items, it should still read "list 4 items". I have an initial fix to hide the first item from screen reader if it is hidden. Due to that hide, Now the screen reader says "list 3 items". Which is wrong.

Comment: @slugolicious To clarify using same amex example. When user clicks right arrow, the first item is hidden from view. Lets say the user tabs around the page and come back to this section again. That first item which is hidden, should not be read out by screen reader cos its not in view. But by hiding this first item, new issue introduced where the screen reader reads out "list 3 items" instead of remaining as "list 4 items".

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 visible items, the screen reader should say that there are 3 items.
You shouldn't trick into making it say that there are 6, it would be incorrect and would lead to confusion.

From a screen reader perspective, there are basically two possible ways to view your carousel component. None is perfect.

#### Paginated list

There is no problem to make it so that only 3 items are visible among a list of 6. Simply put, that's a paginated list.
Some points to consider if you go that way:

1. You should indicate somewhere explicitly that items 1 to 3 are visible out of a total of 6, or that you are on page 1 of 2, independently from the automatic number of visible items announced by the screen reader
2. Buttons to move to previous / next page must be screen reader accessible
3. Don't move to another page without user interaction
4. For a better understanding, pressing the previous / next button should move 3 items at a time rather than just 1.

For point 3, I'm thinking about timed carousels where the content periodically change without user intervention. It's very annoying for a screen reader user when you have read items 1 to 3, want to go back to read them again, and notice that they have been replaced by something else.
Or worse, when some content disappears while reading is still in progress.

For point 4, as a screen reader user, if items 1 to 3 are visible, I normally expect to see items 4 to 6 after having pressed the next button, rather than items 2 to 4.
If you do so and if the indication of which items are currently visible isn't very clear, I might conclude that the next button doesn't work if I encounter again items #2 and #3 that I already have read.

Just a technical thought: why don't you use display:none, rather than more complicated CSS and aria-hidden ?
It's much simpler to develop, and is guaranteed to work absolutely everywhere.

#### Always see everything

As you can read on the paginated list point of view explained above, there are several important points to consider in order to make it accessible, and this isn't always easy to make tradeoffs.

In fact, making your component so that everything is always visible for screen readers isn't necessarily a bad thing.

1. You don't need to care about timed carousels, or the fact that the next button will only scroll one item rather than an entire page
2. As a screen reader user, it's much simpler to have many items read in a row, rather than having the need to change page every few items, especially when the number of items per page is very low (such as 3)
3. Your previous / next buttons don't need to be screen reader accessible, and in fact, since they are completely useless to screen reader users, you should maybe hide them from accessibility tree

For point 2, having a lot of items isn't a problem at all, but under the important condition that there are ways to skip items or the entire list easily.
If you have a good page structure, are using headings, landmarks and such, there's nothing special more to do, but if you don't, then having a lot of items would be a problem.

For point 3, I say maybe, because in fact it isn't easy as putting aria-hidden.
The buttons must stay actionnable for users of voice control, as well as keyboard only users who don't use a screen reader, among others.
So this is another tradeoff....
The most universally accessible would probably be to keep them in the accessibility tree as normal, but making clear for screen reader users that they are totally useless for them, for example by putting a label like "scroll to the left".

There's, however, a new issue for keyboard-only users who don't use a screen reader:
what happens if the focus goes to a link present in a currently hidden item ?
You must take care of that.

Just a thought: instead of previous/next buttons that in fact just do scrolling in this case, why don't you use native scrollbars ?

#### Wrapping up

None of the two are perfect, but probably that you'd better to go for a paginated list point of view.

- All users well now the concept of paginated list, because they are everywhere
- You don't create a completely different user experience for normal users than screen reader users (i.e. see always everything vs. see only 3 items at a time), which may by the way also create problems for other groups of users